# rviz error - Segmentation fault

Tags: ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS electric (Ubuntu 10.04).

I get this error message when I like to start rviz with rosrun rviz rviz:

```
INFO [1347807197.728174501]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
INFO [1347807197.728302839]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3
INFO [1347807197.728350850]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
INFO [1347807197.801335753]: Loading general config from [/home/janina/.rviz/config]
INFO [1347807197.801921520]: Loading display config from [/home/janina/.rviz/display_config]
INFO [1347807197.850185850]: RTT Preferred Mode is Copy.
INFO [1347807198.050808370]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
INFO [1347807198.051192494]: Texture for pass 1: creating with size 1 x 1
INFO [1347807199.082435434]: RTT Preferred Mode is Copy.

**Segmentation fault**
```

I tried export `OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy` (also `PBuffer`, or `FBO`), but it does not work.

Does anybody know an other solution for this problem?

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43912/rviz-error---segmentation-fault/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-09-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm also using electric and have this issue. However, depending on the exact Segfault message, it appears that it is fixed in fuerte and probably will not be fixed in electric.

I suggest you take a look here, sections 3 and 4 : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

And, regards to specific errors...
BadDrawable error : https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5379

Mesa bug : See near bottom that shows "rosrun rviz rviz -sync" https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4830

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0